# Missing several characters for Urdu and Sindhi languages

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, qtwebkit, wicked-pdf, urdu

I'm trying to generate pdf with wicked-pdf gem. Pdf is generated through Qt WebKit rendering engine, so I had to install fonts on the server-side for non-utf languages like Myanmar, Urdu, Pashto etc. It works in most cases, but there is a problem with Urdu and Sindhi language. Some characters are missing resulting in rectangles showed on screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Since there are around 120 languages I have already tried tons of font packages (including official Urdu packages):

```
fonts-indic fonts-thai-tlwg-ttf fonts-lklug-sinhala  fonts-khmeros fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-unfonts-core fonts-noto fonts-nafees ibus-m17n fonts-myanmar
```